# C# find user input in datagridview MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, forms

Im trying to search a string from a textbox and display only the columns with that string inside them but it doesn't seem work well.

```
Database db = new Database();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `students` 
LIKE 
@studentEnrollment%'", db.GetConnection());
            MySqlParameter nameParameter = command.CreateParameter();

            command.Parameters.Add("@studentEnrollment", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = student_search_input;

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(dataset);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
```

Comment: That is not legal SQL - you may want to go back to your learning source and study that.  And filters such as WHERE and LIKE will restrict the result to certain *rows* not columns.  `SELECT *` specifically means 'give me all the columns'.  **Then** re-refine your post to ask a specific question and give a better problem statement than *it doesn't seem work well*.  And if it is already in a DGV (as per the title) you dont need to find it, just use a `RowFilter`

Comment: i started to learn sql today so im not familiar with what I need to do, I have already searched for hours and tried different things I just need an idea of how I can filter the datagridview

Comment: Highly recommended resource: **[SQL Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)**

Comment: I'm missing a part. Guess.. SELECT * FROM students **WHERE name** LIKE '@..'  for LIKE syntax in MySql refer to https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/

Comment: Yea sorry about that part you're right. Also I know almost everything in my app is wrong but I have 3 days to learn c# winform and how SQL and databases work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sketchy solution that worked for me. I just added +'%'

```
command.Parameters.Add("@studentEnrollment", MySqlDbType.String).Value = 
 student_search_input.Text+'%';
```